# ASP MVC 5 Google OAuth2 not working after deploying to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

[image]I have a ASP MVC5 application and i'm using Google OAuth for syncing with google calendar.

that works fine when i'm running the app in Visual studio and Google login page opened in a new tab and everything find. but after deploying into IIS, nothing happened and Google login page not opened.
no error in developer tools and just the request is pending.

i turn off firewall, enable http redirect, try every browser but no progress :(

please help me if anyone faced with same problem.

**EDIT:**

no error occurred and just pending in developer tools window. just after some minutes ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Comment: What error logs are you getting?

Comment: no error. just timeout and ERR_Connection_Reset in browser. I attached Scrrenshot  above.

Comment: Hi, did you find solution for this? i am facing similar situation.